# Does coffee cause children to grow slower?

Tags: recreational-drugs, coffee

One of the things claimed by several adults when I was little is that coffee would stop me from growing so I wasn't allowed to drink it, is there any truth to that claim?

It doesn't seem completely out of order that it could have some negative effects on us considering that it's a [natural pesticide](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/226/4671/184), and that it [reduces the life expectancy of fruit flies](http://biomedgerontology.oxfordjournals.org/content/63/2/149.extract).

Comment: Hi Kit - can you ask a specific question here? What is the specific claim you want analyzed? I doubt there is any research checking whether coffee is "good" or "bad". :-)

Comment: Why not? I don't see why asking a question like "Is smoking bad for you?" is wrong when there should be plenty of evidence that suggests it causes cancer and heart problems for very little benefit. I outlined several claims about coffee and was asking if the health implications of drinking coffee has ever been investigated beyond specifics. I would think this is perfectly in line with: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1367/is-it-true-that-circumcision-leads-to-a-net-increase-in-quality-of-life

Comment: @Kit, I've only asked you to improve your question. It surely could use some improvement by focusing it. The question you linked also suffers from the same problem and is, in fact, becoming quite subjective and argumentative (see the comments on my answer for example).

Comment: I don't really see why evaluating the current state of things and not coming up with a definite answer, or why controversy is a problem, if anything we should welcome the critical evaluation. I will narrow my question.

Comment: I find the question much more interesting in its current incarnation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be more about **caffeine** than coffee.

In 2008, due to [this study](http://www.bmj.com/content/337/bmj.a2332) that suggested that **caffeine intake during pregnancy could increase the risk of fetal growth restriction**, the **"UK Government's Food Standards Agency"** issued [new advice to pregnant women on daily caffeine consumption](http://www.food.gov.uk/news/pressreleases/2008/nov/caffeineadvice):

> **Pregnant women are being advised to
>   limit their daily caffeine intake,
>   ideally keeping this below 200mg a day**
>   (previously it was 300mg). This is
>   roughly two mugs of coffee a day,
>   although caffeine is also present in
>   tea, chocolate, some soft drinks, and
>   certain medicines.

...

> **Too much caffeine might result in a
>   baby having a lower birth weight than
>   it should**, which can increase the risk
>   of some health conditions for the baby
>   in later life, or could possibly
>   result in spontaneous miscarriage.

...

> **We would emphasise that the risks are
>   likely to be very small** and believe
>   our new advice, which is based on new
>   research and has been considered by
>   leading independent scientists, is
>   sensible and proportionate.

---

As stated above, caffeine isn't just in coffee, it can also be found in (ice-)tea, soft and energy drinks, cocoa and chocolate. I'd guess these sources for caffeine are more common for children than coffee.

[Here](http://www.energyfiend.com/the-caffeine-database) is a list of caffeinated beverages (including the amount of caffeine in it).

---

[BabyCenter](http://www.babycenter.com/404_is-it-true-that-caffeine-can-stunt-a-childs-growth_10310763.bc) has this to say:

> No. Caffeine has plenty of undesirable
>   effects, but interfering with a
>   child's growth isn't one of them.
>
> The United States hasn't established
>   recommended limits for kids' caffeine
>   consumption. In Canada, it's
>   recommended that kids ages 4 to 6 get
>   no more than 45 mg a day, kids ages 7
>   to 9 get no more than 62.5 mg, and
>   kids ages 10 to 12 get no more than 85
>   mg.